# I don't understand how mixins works

Tags: ruby

I have 2 modules:

```
module A
  def name
    puts "REAL"
  end
end

module B
  def name
    puts "FAKE"
  end
end
```

When I include them in my class like below:

```
class ABC
  include A
  include B
end
```

output of `ABC.new.name` would be:

```
"FAKE"
```

But when I include modules like below:

```
class ABC
  include B
  include A
end
```

output of `ABC.new.name` would be:

```
"REAL"
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Are you sure your code behaves like this? I just tested it, cannot reproduce...

Comment: I tested it. It is showing either REAL or FAKE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While both modules define method with the same name the method which actually remains in your class is the last included.

Comment: Yeah, but why does it output "FAKE" and "REAL" twice?

Comment: Are you sure? I tested it no such behaiviour

Comment: I don't know, it's not my question

Comment: @Mischa It gives one value either `FAKE` or `REAL`, but @SpunkyLive is using  `ABC.new.name` twice may be !!

Comment: @Prashant4020 he edited his question. Only one output actually.

Comment: -1. There is no method "remaining in the class". No methods get added, removed, or overwritten. They get overridden. It's just basic inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get this behavior:

```
irb(main):121:0* module A
irb(main):122:1>   def name
irb(main):123:2>     puts "REAL"
irb(main):124:2>   end
irb(main):125:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):128:0* module B
irb(main):129:1>   def name
irb(main):130:2>     puts "FAKE"
irb(main):131:2>   end
irb(main):132:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):133:0> class ABC
irb(main):134:1>   include A
irb(main):135:1>   include B
irb(main):136:1> end
=> ABC
irb(main):137:0> ABC.new.name
FAKE
=> nil
irb(main):143:0> class XYZ
irb(main):144:1>   include B
irb(main):145:1>   include A
irb(main):146:1> end
=> XYZ
irb(main):147:0> XYZ.new.name
REAL
=> nil
```

Which makes sense - the last module included gets to define the method. Perhaps there's something else going on in your program?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a step back: what is a mixin? Gilad Bracha didn't invent mixins (they were invented as a design pattern in the *Flavors* object-oriented extension to Lisp Machine Lisp), but he wrote the seminal paper on them (his PhD thesis ["*The Programming Language 'Jigsaw': Mixins, Modularity and Multiple Inheritance*"](http://bracha.org/jigsaw.ps)), in which he *defines* what mixins are, and shows that mixin composition subsumes all other forms of classical inheritance. According to this paper, a mixin is a class parameterized by its superclass. So, you can think of a mixin as a *function :: `Class → Class`*.

What does that mean, exactly? Well, since the mixin is parameterized by its superclass, it doesn't *know* its superclass. When the mixin is mixed into a class, it gets supplied its superclass. A mixin may be mixed in multiple times in the inheritance graph, every time with a different superclass. Note: this is exactly dual to multiple inheritance: in multiple inheritance, a class only exists *once* but may have *many* superclasses. In mixin composition, a mixin exists *many* times, but each instance has only *one* superclass.

How does this work in Ruby?

Let's again take a step back, and look at what a module in Ruby looks like operationally. A module has:

- a method table
- a constant table
- a class variable table

And what does a class look like? A class IS-A module, so it has all of the above, and in addition, it has:

- a superclass pointer

What happens, when you `include` a module `M` into a class `C` like this?

```
class C
  include M
end
```

Well, first off, [`Module#include`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-include) is a method just like any other method. There's nothing special about it. Its default implementation looks a bit like this:

```
class Module
  def include(mod)
    mod.append_features(self)
    included(mod)
  end
end
```

So, in the end, it calls the [`included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-included) hook method, but we're gonna ignore that here. It delegates the actual mixin composition to the mixin. (This means that a mixin can decide how it wants to be mixed in, by overriding the default `Module#append_features`! This is only very rarely used, however, but e.g. `ActiveSupport::Concern` uses it for metaprogramming.)

Now we have just pushed the question around. What does [`append_features`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-append_features) do? Well, it is again a method just like any other, it can be overridden, it can be monkey-patched, it can be removed (*not* a good idea!). However, its default implementation can *not* be expressed in Ruby.

What it does, is:

1. create a new class, let's call it `M′`
2. set `M′`'s method table pointer to `M`'s method table (and ditto for the constant table and class variable table)
3. set `M′`'s superclass pointer to `C`'s superclass
4. set `C`'s superclass pointer to `M′`

Effectively making `M′` the new superclass of `C`, and making the old superclass of `C` the superclass of `M′`, or put another way, insert `M′` directly above `C` in the inheritance tree.

Why is it done this way? Because it keeps method lookup extremely simple: the method lookup algorithm doesn't need to know about mixins at all, it is still the exact same algorithm as it would look like in a language without mixins:

1. get the receiver's class pointer
2. if the class has the method, execute it, otherwise, get the superclass pointer and repeat step 2
3. if the class pointer is empty, call [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) passing the name of the method and the arguments along (unless the name of the method is `method_missing`, then `raise` a [`NoMethodError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/NoMethodError.html) exception)

Note that the meat of the algorithm is simply a very tight `while` loop in step 2. Tight simple loops are good, after all, method lookup is *the* most often executed operation in an object-oriented language implementation.

Now, you might say, "wait, I have asked `C` for its `superclass` and it does *not* return `M′`, it returns `Object`!" Yes, that's true. However, [`Class#superclass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Class.html#method-i-superclass) does not simply return the superclass pointer, unlike the method lookup algorithm, *it does* know about mixins. Or, rather, it knows about what the developers of YARV call *virtual classes*, and it knows to skip them, when returning the superclass. *Virtual classes* are a name that is used internally in YARV. It refers to *include classes* (i.e. the classes I described above, which get created during `include`) and *singleton classes*. Reflective methods know how to treat them specially, e.g. [`Object#class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-class) and `Class#superclass` ignore them, [`Module#ancestors`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) knows to return the module `M` instead of the include class `M′`.

---

I will pause here, to let you run the `append_features` algorithm and the method lookup algorithm for your code on a piece of paper, so that you can figure out for yourself *why* you are seeing the results you are seeing.

---

Okay, so, how does that look like in your example?

We have our class `ABC` which has `Object` as its superclass. Out current inheritance tree looks like this:

```
ABC → Object
```

Now, we `include` `A`. Which means that an include class `A′` gets inserted right above `ABC`:

```
ABC → A′ → Object
```

We repeat the step with `B`:

```
ABC → B′ → A′ → Object
```

Let's now "run" the method lookup for `name`:

1. get the class pointer of the object. It points to `ABC`.
2. Does `ABC` have a method called `name`? No!
3. Get `ABC`'s superclass pointer. It points to `B′`
4. Does `B′` have a method called `name`? Yes, because it shares its method table with `B` which has a method called `name`.
5. We're done, we found it. Execute it!

I think you can see how that would work the other way round in your second code example.

---

Note: This answer deliberately ignores the existence of [`Module#prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-prepend) and [*Refinements*](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), which complicate matters somewhat.