# Calling super for included method results in "no superclass method" error - ActiveSupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, super, activesupport, activesupport-concern

There is "super" keyword in Ruby that is looking through the ancestors chain in order to find the first method implementation up the chain and execute it. So, this is how it works in Ruby, no surprises:

```
module Mammal
  def walk
    puts "I'm walking"
  end
end
```

```
require '~/Documents/rubytest/super/mammal.rb'

class Cat
  include Mammal

  def walk
    super
  end
end
```

```
2.7.0 :001 > simba = Cat.new
2.7.0 :002 > simba.walk
I'm walking
 => nil
```

Which is the desirable behavior. Now, in Rails there is ActiveSupport::Concern that provides some extra functionality for Modules. Here's what happens if you do **kind of** similar way using ActiveSupport helpers:

```
module MammalMixin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    
  included do
    def show
      @mammal = Mammal.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  include MammalMixin

  def show
    super
  end
end
```

If you reach that controller, this will error out:
**super: no superclass method `show' for #SomeController:0x000055f07c549bc0**

Of course, it's possible to not use "included do" helper and revert to plain Ruby style, but could someone please suggest what exactly in ActiveSupport::Concern prevents "super" from working fine and (maybe) explain the rationale behind this?

I've been looking through the source code in active_support/concern.rb, but failing to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is right in [the documentation of `ActiveSupport::Concern#included`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-included) [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> Evaluate given block **in context of base class**, so that you can write class macros here.

So, here's the content of your block:

> ```rb
> def show
>  @mammal = Mammal.find(params[:id])
> end
> ```

And this block is evaluated *in the context of the base class*, as per the documentation. Now, what happens when you evaluate a method `def`inition expression in the context of a class? You define a method in that class!

So, what you are doing here is you define a method named `show` in the `SomeController` class as if you had written:

```rb
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @mammal = Mammal.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    super
  end
end
```

In other words, your second definition is [*overwriting* the first definition, not *overriding* it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471202/2988), and so *there is no* super method.

The *correct way* to use `ActiveSupport::Concern#included` is like this:

```rb
module MammalMixin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def show
    @mammal = Mammal.find(params[:id])
  end
    
  included do
    acts_as_whatever
  end
end
```

`ActiveSupport::Concern#included`, as the documentation says, is for executing code (such as "class macros" like `acts_as_*`, `has_many`, `belongs_to`, etc.) in the context of the class.

[Here's how including a module *normally* works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32820029/2988):

When you write

```rb
class C
  include M
end
```

You are calling the [`Module#include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-include) method (which is not overriden by [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html) and thus inherited without change).

Now, `Module#include` doesn't actually do anything interesting. It basically just looks like this:

```rb
class Module
  def include(mod)
    mod.append_features(self)
  end
end
```

This is a classic Double Dispatch idiom to give the module full control over how it wants to be included into the class. While *you* are calling

```rb
C.include(M)
```

which means that `C` is in control, it simply delegates to

```rb
M.append_features(C)
```

which puts `M` in control.

What [`Module#append_features`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-append_features) *normally* does, is the following (I will describe it in pseudo-Ruby, because the behavior cannot be explained in Ruby, since the necessary data structures are internal to the engine):

```rb
class Module
  def append_features(base)
    if base.is_a?(Module)
      base.included_modules << self unless base.included_modules.include?(self)
    else
      old_superclass = base.__superclass__

      klazz = Class.new(old_superclass)
      klazz.__constant_table__ = __constant_table__
      klazz.__class_variable_table__ = __class_variable_table__
      klazz.__instance_variable_table__ = __instance_variable_table__
      klazz.__method_table__ = __method_table__
      klazz.__virtual__ = true

      base.__superclass__ = klazz
    end

    included(base)

    self
  end
end
```

So, what happens is that Ruby creates a new class, called an *include class* whose constant table pointer, class variable table pointer, instance variable table pointer, and method table pointer point to the constant table, class variable table, instance variable table, and method table of the module. Basically, we are creating a class that shadows the module.

Then it makes this class the new superclass of the class, and makes the old superclass the superclass of the include class. Effectively, it *inserts* the include class between the class and the superclass into the inheritance chain.

This is done this way, because then [the method lookup algorithm doesn't need to know anything about mixins and can be kept very simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412632/2988): go to the class, check if the method exists, if not fetch the superclass, check if the method exists, and so on, and so forth. Since method lookup is one of the most common and most important operations in an execution engine for an OO language, it is crucial that the algorithm is simple and fast.

This *include* class will be skipped by the [`Class#superclass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-superclass) method, so you don't see it, but it will be displayed by [`Module#ancestors`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-ancestors).

And that is why `super` works: because the module *literally* becomes a superclass.

We start off with with `C < Object` and we end up with `C < M' < Object`.

Now, [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) completely screws with this.

The interesting part of the [`ActiveSupport::Concern#included` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/concern.rb#L153-L168) is this:

> ```rb
> @_included_block = block
> ```

It simply stores the block for later use.

As I explained above, when `MammalMixin` gets included into `SomeController`, i.e. when `SomeController.include(MammalMixin)` gets called, `SomeController.include` (which is `Module#include`) will in turn call `MammalMixin.append_features(SomeController)`. `MammalMixin.append_features` in this case is [`ActiveSupport::Concern#append_features`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/concern.rb#L127-L138), and the most interesting part is this:

> ```rb
> base.class_eval(&@_included_block) if instance_variable_defined?(:@_included_block)
> ```

As you can see, it is using [`Module#class_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) in order to evaluate the block it saved earlier in the context of the base class it is included into. And that's what makes your method end up as an instance method of the base class instead of the module.

Comment: Jörg, I can't tell how impressed I am with the quality of your detailed answer! Thank you so much for digging into this as deep as possible, hopefully, this will be useful not only for me, but other people as well! This is *super* clear now :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that `included` is not doing the same thing as your first example, it's a custom hook defined by `ActiveSupport::Concern` that allows you to write class macros (like adding a `scope` to an `ActiveModel`). Under the hood here's what included does:

```
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      <your-block-executes-here>
    end
  end
```

So when pass a block into `included`, that block is being evaluated on the class directly and there's no `super` to reference; you're essentially *overwriting* the method, not *overriding*

Comment: The OP is using mixins in *both* examples, and `super` clearly works in the first but not the second. They are asking *why* it doesn't work in the second. The answer "because mixins" is clearly wrong, as demonstrated in the question.

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer to address the key difference @JörgWMittag

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! That is something I suspected is happening, but was not too sure, thank you for the clarification. I believe this is the part, though I'm not sure where this method gets executed from https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/357e15290ab06af8b4f32dd480b48a8c6e31e9e7/activesupport/lib/active_support/concern.rb#L136